# Adjusted Pearsons residuals after Chi square test for independence are very large. Is it an issue?

Tags: chi-squared-test, residuals, contingency-tables

*Note: it's the first time I conduct this kind of analysis (about Pearson's residuals, not Chi squared), so I have no other reference point to know if my results make sense or not.*

I performed a Chi square test on a 2-way contingency table, got a p-value < 0.05, and wanted to understand which cells were contributing the most.

I understood that to do so, I needed to standardize and adjust the residuals, in order to make them akin to a z-score (even if, admittedly, I didn't really understand the logic behind the adjustment part). Here's the formula:

$$\frac{O_{ij}-E_{ij}}{\sqrt{E_{ij} \cdot ({1-{E_{ij}\over \mathrm{RowTotal}}}) \cdot ({1-{E_{ij} \over \mathrm{ColumnTotal}})}}}$$

However, after obtaining the results, I see most of them are extremely high: some even > 10! To me, this doesn't make much sense, since these should be z-scores, and having a z-score 10 standard deviations above the mean sounds extremely unlikely.

Any idea how I can interpret such results?

Edit: chi squared value is 560.

For the record, here's my contingency table and adjusted residuals:

```
crosstab:

        y1      y2      y3      y4

x1    4878     611    1171    3627
x2     567     186     171     296
x3    1253     231     841    1371
x4     439      69     133     254
```

```
adj residuals:

            y1      y2      y3      y4

x1       11.52   -5.27  -12.13    2.90
x2        1.60   13.45   -0.38   -7.17
x3      -12.90   -1.53   19.12    3.96
x4        3.06    1.10    0.42   -3.75
```

Comment: What was chi-square?

Comment: @JeremyMiles yo, it was 560. Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: A large z-score is extremely unlikely *only when the null hypothesis is true.*  Indeed, a chi-squared value of 560, when split among 9 degrees of freedom, averages out to about 60 per squared residual, so -- taking the square root -- you should expect this chi-squared statistic to reflect some absolute z-scores less than 8 and it *must* have some greater than 8.  On this basis, a glance at your output suggests everything is as it should be.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, that is comforting. I'm still a novice for this kind of things and thus I am unaware of certain details such as the one you just pointed out. Could you direct me towards any resource that explains your reasoning? As of now I'm failing to understand the logic

Comment: I would recommend any intro stats textbook: they all cover chi-squared tests and their interpretations.

Comment: Fair enough :D!